# removing entities in OneToMany with RequestFactory & JPA

Tags: java, gwt, jpa, requestfactory

I would like to know what's the right way to remove a child from a one-to-many relation within GWT using the RequestFactory.

My GWT application with an Entity called **Product** and that product has a one-to-many relation to an **Expert**:

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    ... 
    OneToMany(mappedBy="product", orphanRemoval=true,
              cascade={CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH},fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    Set<Expert> experts = new HashSet<Expert>();
    ...
}

@Entity(name = "EXPERT")
public class Expert {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    Product product;
    ...
}
```

I have a user-interface where you can change some values of Product, but also a window where experts can be added or removed. Adding a Expert goes well, but how do I remove an expert? And what administration must I do on the client and server side?

I have already an opened productRequest going on.

Comment: It looks like this question is more related to JPA in general so I added another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945852

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered your JPA question as well.

Base on my past experience, removing a child in parent-child bi-directional relationship in Hibernate can be very tricky.

What I usually do is use uni-directional mapping instead, i.e. Product does not hold the set of experts. But you can implement a getter to get all experts using Hibernate call. The advantages are:

1. easier mapping
2. easier coding
3. manageable behviour

You can always come back and implement caching or eager fetching at later stage. And most of the time they are unnecessary pre-mature optimization.

Comment: I've finally managed to get everything working, but as you said, it can be quite tricky and it looks clear and easy, but can be hard in practice. I'm sure for a next project I will choose my relations more carefully as the implementation is more difficult (or restrictive) than expected.