# remove an entity in OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have trouble understanding what minimal effort is needed on my part in removing an Entity from a OneToMany relationship. I find a lot of examples just adding Entities to these sets (and that works out allright), but removing entities is much more difficult to find.

I have the following class:

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    ... 
    OneToMany(mappedBy="product", orphanRemoval=true,
              cascade={CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH},fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    Set<Expert> experts = new HashSet<Expert>();
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Expert {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    Product product;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    Person person;

    ...
}
```

(Person is similar to Product)

I have it filled with Products and experts. I want to remove an expert from the list of products so the expert entity is removed completely. I would expect that either the following code would be enough:

```
Product aProduct = findAProduct(...);
Expert anExpert aProduct.getExperts.get(...); // Just get the first expert that I want removed
EntityManager em = entityManager();

  em.getTransaction().begin();
  aProduct.getExperts().remove(anExpert);
  em.merge(aProduct);
  em.getTransaction().commit();
```

or:

```
  em.getTransaction().begin();
  em.remove(anExpert);
  em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Is this too simplistic? What is done by JPA and what do I have to do myself? I have solved it before by just using queries but I expect that JPA can do this for me.

Comment: Have you tried those two techniques? What does it give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get it working was to do the following:

```
EntityManager em = entityManager();
// Retrieve the expert in the new EntityManager context 
Expert expertToDelete = em.find(Expert.class, anExpert.id);

em.getTransaction().begin();
expertToDelete.getProduct().getExperts().remove(expertToDelete);
expertToDelete.getPerson().getExperts().remove(expertToDelete);
em.remove(expertToDelete);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

It could very well be that instead of retrieving the expert via the find, you can use a merge() on anExpert instead, but the above seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
aProduct = em.merge(aProduct);
aProduct.getExperts().remove(anExpert);    
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

The problem is with the merge operation, not with remove.

Answer (score 1):

Base on my past experience, removing a child in parent-child bi-directional relationship in Hibernate can be very tricky.

What I usually do is use uni-directional mapping instead, i.e. Product does not hold the set of experts. But you can implement a getter to get all experts using Hibernate call. The advantages are:

1. easier mapping
2. easier coding
3. manageable behviour

You can always come back and implement caching or eager fetching at later stage. And most of the time they are unnecessary pre-mature optimization.